# Why is my console.log in LWC showing variable data in proxy handler

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc, sfdc

I'm trying to `console.log` a variable's value but on the browser console instead of printing the variable (an object in my case), I am getting a Proxy container with format like
`Proxy {}[[Handler]]: En[[Target]]: Array(0)[[IsRevoked]]: false`

On opening the `[[Handler]]`, I get some inner properties which contains an `originalTarget` property.
On expanding the `originalTarget` , my data is shown.

How do I get this data to show properly in console and also access it in my LWC ?

[this.variableName returns value in a Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpLAS.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view proxy data so use this :

```
JSON.stringify(this.caseList)
```

And further if you want to use it in your lwc use this:

```
let cases = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.caseList))
console.log(cases);
```

I hope you find the above solution helpful. If it does, please mark it as Best Answer to help others too.

Answer (score -1):

Reason : whenever we mark any Javascript object as @track, Salesforce wraps the object inside creating proxy objects.

Solution: @Rajat Jaiswal answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).